# VBA Excel - Loop based on cell range value

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

So I'm running a loop to grab data from one column on a different sheet and I want it to stop once the data in the column ends, but I'm having some trouble finding a condition to end the loop.

```
Do While values(i) <> 0

Set xcell = Range(Cells(x + 3, 2), Cells(x + 3, 2))
Set ycell = Range(Cells(y + 3, 2), Cells(y + 3, 2))
x = x + 1
y = y + 1

ycell.Formula = "='\\Drcs8570168\shasad\[CR Status.xlsx]Sheet1'!" & xcell.Address

values(i + 1) = xcell.Value
i = i + 1

Loop
```

I tried to assign each cell to a variable with an array and run the loop until blank cells start to be recorded. It tells me that the subscript is out of range.

Comment: How are you declaring **values()** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you intialized the variable `i` and the array `values`?

Before the loop:

```
i=0
Redim Preserve valus(i)
values(i)=1 'or else we will never enter the loop
```

In the loop (the last lines before the loop statement):

```
i = i + 1
Redim Preserve values(i)
values(i) = xcell.Value
```

But you don't even need the array `values` (that is if you will not use it anywhere else in your code), just store the last cell value in `i`.

Before the loop:

```
i = 1 'or we won't enter the loop
while i<>0 'starting the loop
```

here comes your looping code, and then before the end of the loop:

```
i = xcell.Value
Loop
```

EDIT:
But if you have an actual 0 as cell-value in your list, the loop will stop before the end of the list, so you might want rather to check whether your cell contains no characters:

Assuming:

```
Dim i as Variant
```

The loop condition in the last example could then also be:

```
while i<>""
```

And this will only stop if the cell is really empty (=has no contents)

Comment: So I put 
    ReDim Preserve values(i) 
    values(i) = 1
But it still says out of range
And I was hoping to keep the cell contents in the array, that's why i wasn't just using i for the loop.

Comment: Actually, one thing I didn't notice before is that I do get an output of the first cell in the loop, but then I get the "type mismatch" error.

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake. The code did work, just forgot the redim line.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, instead of:

```
Set xcell = Range(Cells(x + 3, 2), Cells(x + 3, 2))
```

Use just:

```
Set xcell = Cells(x + 3, 2)
```

**BUT**, I would doubt that you even need to loop at all.  Try something like this:

```
Dim vValues As Variant

'// Get the range of cells you want to work with
With Range("B3", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    '// Add the formula, excel will automatically fill in series
    .Formula = "='\\Drcs8570168\shasad\[CR Status.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1"
    '// Build an array from the values
    vValues = .Value
End With
```

Comment: Hmm, I would like to try this out but I'm not familiar with those commands. Even though you wouldn't want to use a loop would you know why mine isn't working?

Comment: The commands may look a little complex to start with, but they are really not. All it does it gets the used cells of column b, then fills them with a formula and populates and array from them.  Please edit your post to include the entire code, I need to see declarations and what the initial values of x and y are etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a function to find the last row with data in it such as:

```
Function LastRow(wks As Worksheet) As Long
    On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    LastRow = wks.Cells.Find("*", After:=wks.Cells(1, 1), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Exit Function
ErrHandle:
    LastRow = 0
End Function
```

Comment: What happens if you don't include the optional argument?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not even sure why that argument is optional. I wrote this a while ago when I was first learning VBA and I can't really recall why I wrote it like that. I've edited my post to make the argument required.

Comment: This function will return the last used row that occurs *anywhere* in the sheet, but the user wants the last used row in a particular column (or columns). So while I would use Reafidy's approach, I would suggest you tailor the Find to search discrete columns to be applicable to this issue. Cheers.